# STM32F4 Fewer Pin Mapping possibilities for ADC inputs

Tags: adc, stm32, gpio, stm32f4, stm32cubemx

For STM32F405 100pin package, its [datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/dm00037051.pdf) page 39 and [ref. manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00031020.pdf) page 388 as well as CubeMX shows that there are 3 ADCs each share 16-channels as shown in following images.

Although it is not explicitly mentioned in the above documents but my research has shown me that these 16 input channels can only be used at the specified 16 pins of the MCU chip and they cannot be mapped to any other pins as alternate functions. This research is based on Table 7 page 47 of the above datasheet.

Please correct me if I am wrong in the above conclusion of my research.

So my question is that if there are 16 channels and there are fix 16 pins then does that mean that there is only 1 ADC of 16-channels instead of the the 3 ADCs as mentioned in the above documents?

[image: from Datasheet page 39]

[image: from Ref. manual page 388]

Comment: The datasheet language seems pretty clear to me. Do you have some reason to think that the datasheet is incorrect?

Comment: What I cannot understand from datasheet is that why does it says 3 ADC when there are only 16 fixed pins for the ADCs..

Comment: How many pins do you think there should be for 3 ADCs? Why would you expect that there should be more than 16?

Comment: Have you studied the Block Diagram (on page 389)?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I am trying to understand here. If there are 3 ADCs each with 16 input channels then 48 pins can be there on the MCU but there are only 16 pins on the chip. On each of these 16 pins we can select a channel from any one of the 3 ADCs. To me it is same as 1 ADC with 16 channels. Obviously I am missing some important point here if you can help.

Comment: @Tyler Yes I seen it. It also shows only 16 pins for the ADC channels. This is for only 1 ADC. How are the other 2 ADCs fit into this? Are they parallel to this ADC from the channel input pins point of view.. or are they separate?

Comment: Sorry if the world was not built to your liking...

Comment: "... shares UP TO 16 channels"

Comment: The information you seek begins on page 47 of your own link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 16 analog input pins. There are 3 AD converters. A single AD converter can only select any (one) channel of the 16 inputs for performing a conversion. Given that, with 3 AD converters, you can sample any three analog inputs out of the 16 inputs simultaneously at the same time, instead of reading all three one after another with single AD converter.

Comment: It seems to be the conversion time/sample rate which was not appreciated by the original question.

Answer (score 1):

There are 16 analog inputs, but CubeMX says for the STM32F405 100pin package, ADC3 is only connected to 8 of them:

IN0-3 (PA0-PA3) and IN10-13 (PC0-PC3).

The extra pins for ADC3 are off of Port F, which is not on the 100 pin package.

[ADC3 pins](https://stm32f4-discovery.net/2014/04/library-06-ad-converter-on-stm32f4xx/)

ADC1 & ADC2 are connected to all 16.  So it appears there are differences, which are not reflected in documentation.

[image: CubeMX pins]

[image: CubeMX ADC3]

Comment: You could just read the data sheet, it shows the possibilities for each pin and indicates which packages *have* that pin...

Comment: @ChrisStratton  Actually the extra pins are off of Port F.

Comment: Again, all of this is right there in the table that begins on page 47 of the data sheet linked in the question itself.

Comment: I'm not denying that, but CubeMX was created to make that process easier.